# How to add points for users of my app and connect it to android?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have started working on one project, but i'm stucked here where i need to add points for every users i have stored already in my database. I have created one database where i'm storing username and password for user and connected it to android. Everything is working, but now in my case i would like to store points for users when they solved something for example in my app, but i don't know how to write methods for that and need a little help in php to do that.

**These are my php files:** *Register.php*

```
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "geomondo");  

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    //$username = "admin";
    //$password = "admin";

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO User (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**and one more:** *FetchUserData.php*

```
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "geomondo");  

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    //$username = "test";
    //$password = "test";

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $username, $password);

    $user = array();

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $user["username"] = $username;
        $user["password"] = $password;
    }

    echo json_encode($user);
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

So how would i now include here also points for every user?

**This is my java file for connecting android to php and mysql:**

```
    public class ServerRequests {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 1000 * 15;
    public static final String SERVER_ADRESS = "http://192.168.0.17:8081/project/";

    public ServerRequests(Context context){
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setTitle(R.string.progress_dialog);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    }

    public void storeUserDataInBackground(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback){
        progressDialog.show();
        new StoreUserDataAsyncTask(user, userCallback).execute();
    }

    public void fetchUserDatainBackground(User user, GetUserCallback callBack){
        progressDialog.show();
        new fetchUserDataAsyncTask(user, callBack).execute();
    }

    public class StoreUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        User user;
        GetUserCallback userCallback;

        public StoreUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback){
            this.user = user;
            this.userCallback = userCallback;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));

            HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADRESS + "Register.php");

            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                client.execute(post);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            userCallback.done(null);
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }

    public class fetchUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, User> {
        User user;
        GetUserCallback userCallback;

        public fetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback) {
            this.user = user;
            this.userCallback = userCallback;
        }

        @Override
        protected User doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));

            HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADRESS + "FetchUserData.php");

            User returnedUser = null;
            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

                HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);

                if (jObject.length() == 0)
                {
                    returnedUser = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    returnedUser = new User(user.username, user.password);
                }

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return returnedUser;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(User returnedUser) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            userCallback.done(returnedUser);
            super.onPostExecute(returnedUser);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my first time connecting android to online database and i'm still learning android developing, so i would appricieate any help here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question shows that you have some problems with the basic terms.
[Study it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science)#Server_side_web_sessions).
When you have created an account, (incidentally the database is best not to store the [password but its hash](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)) you are exactly the same may log: sending a username and password. If it exists in database create [session in php](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sessions.htm).

```
//here we are looking for a user in the database. I do not know how to work with mysqli
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = $login;
```

([better use id to store the user's session](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html))

Now you will be able to determine from a user's request arrived (via sessions)

```
if ($_SESSION['name'] != '')
```

and add data to the table.

```
id | login | score
```

This is the simplest solution. Good luck.